# How would I return the last generic object in a list? Java

Tags: java, generics, methods, linked-list, nodes

This is where I add the object to the list:

```
   public void add (T element)
   {      
       LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T> (element); 

       if (size() == 0) {  
            this.last = node; // last node 
            this.list = node; // first node
            this.count++;
       }//end if
       else
          if (!(contains(element)))
          { 
              last.setNext(node); 
              last = node; 
              count++;   
          } //end if
   }
```

I have to create a method which returns the last object in this list. Could anyone help?

Comment: `public T last() {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `LinearNode<T>` has a method `getValue()` which returns the `T` instance stored in that node.  You already have a `last` reference in your `LinkedList` class, so it should be as simple as

```
public T getLast()
{
    return last.getValue();
}
```

This is just a skeleton, and needs to check for empty list, etc.